# Merge two dataframes via join and consider timestamp

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

Let's say I have this data frame

```
  time1               weight
  <chr>                <dbl>
1 2012-04-25 17:40:00     82
2 2012-04-25 18:40:00     81
```

I now have another data frame of the form:

```
  time2                  d1    d2    d3
  <chr>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2012-04-25 17:45:00     1     0     1
```

I now want to join these dataframes. However, I want to only use the original values in `d1 d2 d3` if the `time2` is greater than `time1`. Otherwise the values should be zero. That is I want:

```
  time1               weight    d1    d2    d3
  <chr>                <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 2012-04-25 17:40:00     82     0     0     0
2 2012-04-25 18:40:00     81     1     0     1
```

What's a sneaky way to do so?

Comment: What are you joining on?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fuzzy-join`:

```r
library(fuzzyjoin)

fuzzy_left_join(df1, df2, by = c("time1" = "time2"), match_fun = `>`)

#                 time1 weight               time2 d1 d2 d3
# 1 2012-04-25 17:40:00     82                <NA> NA NA NA
# 2 2012-04-25 18:40:00     81 2012-04-25 17:45:00  1  0  1
```

The mismatched rows are filled with `NA`. Many functions can replace `NA` with other values so I don't deal with it here.

---

###### Data

```r
df1 <- structure(list(time1 = c("2012-04-25 17:40:00", "2012-04-25 18:40:00"),
weight = 82:81), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

df2 <- structure(list(time2 = "2012-04-25 17:45:00", d1 = 1L, d2 = 0L, d3 = 1L),
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -1L))
```

Comment: can I use this in addition to a grouping variable? So imagine an ID

Comment: @mc1893 I seems that you want to join two data frames by multiple variables. In this case, `match_fun` should be a list of functions one for each pair of columns specified in `by`.

Comment: this seems to work for my initial question thanks so far! However, this seems not to work if my `df2` has multiple rows that fulfill `time1 > time2`. Is there a way to join only the latest possible row from `df2` ? Without any changes, multiple rows are contained in the resulting dataframe - one for each entry in `df2` that fulfills `time1 > time2` :/

Comment: @mc1893 I think it can be achieved. But it's hard to discuss this without any sample data. It's better to make a new post because your problem is beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union

df1 <- tribble(
  ~time1, ~weight,
  "2012-04-25 17:40:00", 82,
  "2012-04-25 18:40:00", 81
) |> rename(time = time1)

df2 <- tribble(
  ~time2, ~d1, ~d2, ~d3,
  "2012-04-25 17:45:00", 1, 0, 1
)|> rename(time = time2)

bind_rows(df1, df2) |> 
  mutate(time = ymd_hms(time)) |> 
  arrange(time) |> 
  fill(-weight) |> 
  filter(!is.na(weight)) |> 
  mutate(across(-time, ~if_else(is.na(.), 0, .)))
#> # A tibble: 2 × 5
#>   time                weight    d1    d2    d3
#>   <dttm>               <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1 2012-04-25 17:40:00     82     0     0     0
#> 2 2012-04-25 18:40:00     81     1     0     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not actually joining anything, you are merely concatenating two data frames, you can do that first and then fix what is wrong. For ex. given your data

```
df1=read.table(text="
time1               weight
'2012-04-25 17:40:00'     82
'2012-04-25 18:40:00'     81",h=T)
df1$time1=as.POSIXct(df1$time1)

df2=read.table(text="
time2                  d1    d2    d3
'2012-04-25 17:45:00'     1     0     1",h=T)
df2$time2=as.POSIXct(df2$time2)
```

you can do

```
df3=cbind(df1,df2)
df3[df3$time2>df3$time1,grepl("d",colnames(df3))]=0

                time1 weight               time2 d1 d2 d3
1 2012-04-25 17:40:00     82 2012-04-25 17:45:00  0  0  0
2 2012-04-25 18:40:00     81 2012-04-25 17:45:00  1  0  1
```